# What types of filter Neo4J composite index does support

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

I was working with janus graph for many months, but it has a very serious problem with index (creating, deleting and re-indexing). for that i am planing to use Neo4j Community edition instead.

While I am reading the documentation of Neo4J, they said that composite index doesn't support: exists(n.prop), n.prop > value, STARTS WITH, ENDS WITH, CONTAINS.
so what kind of filtering does support. moreover when it will be supported according to the plan?

Answer (score 1):

Only exact value comparisons work for composite indexes, and all properties of the composite index must be supplied, none can be omitted. The developers guide should be fairly thorough here, with examples of Cypher matches that would utilize the composite index lookup, as well as examples of nodes that would be indexed vs nodes that don't have values for the relevant properties and would not be indexed.

To my knowledge changing this isn't high priority at the moment. Stick with single property indexes if you need richer index lookup capabilities.